# Masonry not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, masonry

I am using the [masonry package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-masonry) for Angular 2 and I cannot get the spacing to work as expected.  I've updated the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/bCj8b1ePTDKlFaC8EnIE?p=preview) to show what I mean, but basically, the items get pushed all the way to the right or get pushed down the page.

Is there a setting I am missing?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="addBrick()">Add brick</button>
    <masonry [options]="{ percentPosition: true }">
      <masonry-brick class="brick brick-4">brick</masonry-brick>
      <masonry-brick class="brick brick-2">brick</masonry-brick>
      <masonry-brick class="brick brick-2">brick</masonry-brick>
      <masonry-brick class="brick brick-4">brick</masonry-brick>
    </masonry>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .brick { 
      width: 5%;
      background: green;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  `]
})
```